# Is there an Azure AD B2C sample app written in Rust

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Microsoft has provided sample apps written in ASP.NET, Javascript in the documentation for Azure AD B2C:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-web-api-dotnet?tabs=app-reg-ga

I was wondering whether there is something similar written for Rust?

Comment: Are you looking specifically for a Microsoft-provided example?

Comment: @BradC.Not necessarily Microsoft provided. Even a community provided one would do fine.

Comment: Thanks @Attilah and please find the currently document for Rust - and hope this will help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-rust-get-started#review-the-code-optional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Azure Active Directory B2C is a standards-based Single Sign On provider, you can look for any documentation that shows Rust authenticating with something like OpenID, OAuth or SAML.

Example:
https://docs.rs/oidc/0.3.0/oidc/